# 404 when uploading files to Spring J2EE

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, file-upload

My current code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=*")
public void uploadFile(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile multipartFile, 
                    Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
    System.out.println(fileName);
}
```

**Problem is that when I require the file to be there (not having "required=false" after value="file") Then it can't find the suitable path for my request (404).**

I have checked in browsers that there are a file sent to the server, with the name="file":(copy paste from chrome browser follows)

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryS7qP6QevHhFOyAZN
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="testfile"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
------WebKitFormBoundaryS7qP6QevHhFOyAZN--
```

I really could use a hint here, can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were missing the following in mappings:
servlet context.xml:

```
 <beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
     class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

root-context.xml:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
              class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
     <!--25 mb max--> 
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="26214400"/>
</bean>
```

and last In pom.xml (because i run maven project, else you need the jars)

```
<!-- Fileupload dependencies --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version> <!-- makesure correct version here -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
```